# Vertical sub-menu disappears under page on IE7

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-7

The vertical submenu shows fine in all browsers but not in IE7 when I hover over “Diensten”.

[see the website](http://www.marmsoft.nl)

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Its not fine even in IE9. Fix the position absolute top 1.68em for the #access ul ul

Comment: The problem is that the menu disappears behind page on IE7. I don’t have this problem with IE9.
I Have changed the   “top 1.68em ” to see why the menu is not displayed on IE7.
top 1.68em is not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

am i right that you are using css3pie? If yes, try to remove it first, does it work now?

Comment: Yes I use css3pie, but it does not work when I remove css3pie.

Comment: Sorry, Yes It works little bit, when I remove Pie. See website. 
But I cannot use rounded corners  with css3  on IE7 and IE8.

Comment: try to change display: none/ block to visibility: hidden/ visible and positioning if needed

Answer (score 0):

Yes It works little bit, when I remove Pie. See website. 
But I cannot use rounded corners  with css3  on IE7 and IE8.

Comment: this ia a comment not a answer. please follow the rules.